# echoing PROMPT_COMMAND from terminal and from bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, environment-variables

while trying to write a bash script i encountered a strange issue when i try to execute it.
i want to echo the $PROMPT_COMMAND variable thus, i have the following piece of bash script

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
```

executing this script echoes nothing. why is that? it does not make sense as when i do execute

> echo $PROMPT_COMMAND

from the command prompt, i get the content that is stored inside the PROMPT_COMMAND

so... what am i doing wrong, what is missing?

a thing about the environment: tried this on ubuntu 20

Comment: `PROMPT_COMMAND` typically is not an environment variable, as the only shells that care about it already source `.bashrc`. As such, it's not defined in the non-interactive shells that execute your script.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote! Can you also Accept my answer?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is based on how you are executing your script and what environment it is using.

After making the file executable, there are two ways of running it:

1. `./script.sh`
2. `. script.sh`

The first way executes it in a new bash subshell, which doesn't have access to the `$PROMPT_COMMAND` variable since it is by definition, new.

The second way executes the script within the context of your current shell. This means it has access to the `$PROMPT_COMMAND` variable. This is the right way to proceed. Anytime you need to work on your prompt, you need to execute it this way.

> Note: #2 is the same as running `source script.sh`. It is also
> referred to as "sourcing" your script. Just in case you run into these
> terms, you'll know what they mean.